# How do I reverse rigid body?

Tags: animation, text-object, rigidbody

I used rigid body a text to make it fall down.
After it finishes falling, i want to make it to look like it’s rewinding itself to before fall state

Any idea or tips on how to do this?

Comment: Hello, you need to bake the simulation into keyframes (Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes) then reverse the keyframes in the Timeline or Dope Sheet (SX-1)

Comment: This is a site run by volunteers answering question for free on their spare time, rushing them or giving deadlines may be discouraging and is generally considered rude. Among other factors, how fast you get answers depends largely on how thorough your question is. Instead of digressing about deadlines provide factual details to diagnose the issue, [add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), state what you have tried and what research you did about it. Otherwise may be best to seek professional help.

Comment: It works! thanks for the tips moonboots!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bake the simulation into keyframes (*Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes*) then reverse the keyframes in the *Timeline* or *Dope Sheet* (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>)